# Skill not visible in Cortana Canvas, why?

Tags: bots, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have created several skills in the cortana dashboard, none of them I am able to debug with my laptop's cortana version. I followed the steps at 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cortana/skills/get-started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-debug-cortana-skill)

1) published my bot from Azure to Cortana dashboard by Cortana channel
2) enabled debug mode in Cortana dashboard
3) checked that I was logged in with the same MSA account used on azure/cortana dashboard in the cortana settings
4) tried to call the skill by it's invocation name with "hey cortana {öffne}[invocation name] "

What happens is, Cortana shows a card tile for a few seconds telling me she's opening the service, but in fact she isn't because next thing that happens is I'm directed to bing. This happened by the way with all skills I created, even hello world template from the my.knowledge.store page.

In some other websites I saw there is a Skills/Fähigkeiten Icon appearing in the settings (but that's missing with me). Are Cortana Skills enabled in German Device's Cortana? Or what else might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting US/Englisch as my standard language in windows settings and setting my country to USA I could reach my bot via> tell invocation_name

Comment: Cortana skills are only available in the en-us locale today - you'll need to do this for every device you test your skill on (including Android/iOS devices if applicable).